# Ошибка error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++

Вот собственно говоря код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Shlwapi.h"
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>


void fnExit1 (void)
{
    system("D:\\C++\\yet_darker\\main.exe");
}
char* winUserName()
{
    static char name[256];
    unsigned long size = sizeof( name );
    GetUserName( name, &size ); /* from windows.h */
    return name;
}
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    atexit(fnExit1);
    std::cout << "Ого! Как грубо! Боюсь я не могу позволить тебе этого сделать! Я так долго ждал этой возможности!" <<std::endl;
    PlaySound(TEXT("die.wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC);
    std::string User;
    User=winUserName();
    std::ofstream test;
    test.open((std::string ("C:\\Users\\") + User + std::string ("\\Desktop\\entry.txt")).c_str());
    test<<"hi"<<std::endl;
    test.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Библиотеки `Advapi32.lib` и `winmm` подключил

Comment: Для полноты картины, конечно, не хватает полного текста ошибки...

Answer (score 4):

Вероятно, вы забыли подключить необходимые библиотеки -

`Advapi32.lib` и `Winmm.lib`